# Displaying aligned columns in C++

Tags: c++

I am currently doing a project right now where I have to display a range of integers along with 10%, 15%, and 20% discounts for the integers in columns. This is not a problem for me when the numbers have the same amount of character spaces, however this project mixes number such as 5.00 and 10.00. Because 10.00 contains five character spaces and 5.00 contains four, it throws my columns off. I know it is super nit picky but I want to fix it. Is there a way?

```
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double number = 0.0;
        double tenp = 0.0;
        double fifp = 0.0;
        double twep = 0.0;

        cout << "Original price" << setw(13) << "10% off" << setw(20) 
             << "15% off"<< setw(20) << "20% off"<<endl;

        for (double number = 5.0; number < 51; number += 5)
        {
            tenp = number - number*.10;
            fifp = number - number*.15;
            twep = number - number*.20;


            cout << fixed<<setprecision(2);
            cout <<"$ " << number << setw(15)<<"$ " 
                << tenp<< setw(15)<<" $ " 
                << fifp<< setw(15) <<"$ "
                << twep << endl;



        }
        return 0;
    }



    Original price      10% off             15% off             20% off
$ 5.00             $ 4.50             $ 4.25             $ 4.00
$ 10.00             $ 9.00             $ 8.50             $ 8.00
$ 15.00             $ 13.50             $ 12.75             $ 12.00
$ 20.00             $ 18.00             $ 17.00             $ 16.00
$ 25.00             $ 22.50             $ 21.25             $ 20.00
$ 30.00             $ 27.00             $ 25.50             $ 24.00
$ 35.00             $ 31.50             $ 29.75             $ 28.00
$ 40.00             $ 36.00             $ 34.00             $ 32.00
$ 45.00             $ 40.50             $ 38.25             $ 36.00
$ 50.00             $ 45.00             $ 42.50             $ 40.00
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity to just *experiment* with the different [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). Try them out in different order and different places and passign different values, and just see what happens. Sooner or later you will figure it out yourself what needs to be done, giving you useful experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `setfill` to force each number to have the same width by padding with spaces.  First include the header `<iomanip>` then try the following code:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << "$ " << setfill(' ') << setw(13) << number
        "$ " << setfill(' ') << setw(13) << tenp
        "$ " << setfill(' ') << setw(13) << fifp
        "$ " << setfill(' ') << setw(13) << twep << endl;
```

And print your headers with the same spacing so that everything lines up nicely:

```
cout << setw(15) << "Original price"
     << setw(15) << "10% off"
     << setw(15) << "15% off"
     << setw(15) << "20% off" << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback! Unfortunately setfill doesn't work.

Comment: @MattC I updated again.  I think the reason it wasn't working is that I failed to realize that `setw` only works on the field which immediately follows it.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to look at the [stream format flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/).

There are a few that might help.  The simplest might be left padding the strings with spaces:

```
cout.setf(ios::right);
```